# Length of instruction LD A,(C) in gameboy ~Z80 processor

Tags: assembly, emulation, z80, gameboy

Hello I'm writing an emulator for Game Boy.

I use this reference : [Gameboy CPU (LR35902) instruction set](http://www.pastraiser.com/cpu/gameboy/gameboy_opcodes.html)

This document states that opcodes :

```
0xE2 LD (C),A
```

and

```
0xF2 LD A,(C)
```

have a length of 2.

The [Game Boy CPU Manual](http://marc.rawer.de/Gameboy/Docs/GBCPUman.pdf) says that these instructions respectively :

> Put value at address $FF00 + register C into A.

and

> Put A into address $FF00 + register C.

I think it has length of 1 because the opcode is self sufficient, it doesn't need another value to be interpreted. If it has a length of 2, what's the purpose of the second byte ?

Comment: Why do you think that?

Comment: The diagram states that the instructions are 8-bit. I don't see any reason to disbelieve.

Comment: Try this [gameboy cpu reference](http://marc.rawer.de/Gameboy/Docs/GBCPUman.pdf) .

Comment: All the sources say 2 bytes, but none say what the second byte is used for. The gbemulator source doesn't use it for anything, so maybe it's undefined and just a leftover from the original z80 encodings which were repurposed for these gameboy specific instructions.

Comment: I may have badly understood the question, but I've never seen 0xE2 and 0xF2 use a second byte. Here's an example of 0xE2 in GBC: http://datacrystal.romhacking.net/wiki/Yu-Gi-Oh!_Dark_Duel_Stories:ROM_map#LCD_Control

Comment: [pandocs](http://bgb.bircd.org/pandocs.htm#cpuinstructionset) say that they are 1 byte instructions, and that's what I treat them as in my emulator.

Comment: Given the example given by @MégaLag and what [pandocs](http://bgb.bircd.org/pandocs.htm#cpuinstructionset) says, I'll consider it a 1 byte instruction.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are absolutely right. `LD (C),A` and `LD A,(C)` are 1 byte long.

I have even emailed the responsible (Pastraiser) asking for clarification (or if he could fixed the website) but I got no answer.

Another thing that bothers me is the fact that `prefix CB` is considered to be 1 byte long and consume 4 cycles. And all the extended instructions are considered to be 2 bytes long and consume 8 cycles (16 if they access `(HL)`). It would make more sense to me to leave blank the space below `Prefix CB` so it is clear that all extended instructions already include the size and processing cycles of their prefix.

And the other thing that bothers me is the fact that `STOP` length is 2. It is actually just one byte long. There is a hardware bug on Gameboy Classic that causes the instruction following a `STOP` to be skipped. So Nintendo started to tell developers to add a `NOP` always after a `STOP`. So, to be 100% correct I would consider `STOP` to be (1,4) instead of (2,4). This issue does not exist on Gameboy Color.